# Prove or disprove the statement: "The number $1+n+n^2$ is odd for every integer $n$"

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Stuck of this. Do I create statements and a truth table?

Please help

Comment: Check what happens if $n$ is even (so write $n = 2k$) and if $n$ is odd (write $n=2k+1$).

Comment: Hint: $1 + n + n^2 = (n+1)^2 - n$.

Answer (score 5):

Write $1+n+n^2=1+n(n+1)$ and use the fact that the product of two consecutive integers is even (why?).

Answer (score 2):

Let $n=2i$ be even. This gives
$$
n^2+n+1=4i^2+2i+1=2(2i^2+i)+1
$$
which is of the form $2x+1$, and therefore odd.

What happens if $n=2i+1$ is odd?

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is odd, then so is $n^2.$ Hence $n+n^2$ is even. Hence $1+n+n^2$ is odd.

If $n$ is even, then so is $n^2.$ Hence $n+n^2$ is even. Hence $1+n+n^2$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

$$1+n+n^2 \equiv 1+n+n \equiv 1+2n \equiv 1 \mod 2$$